# Bulk rename files inside subfolder, removing prefix

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

I have a bunch of MP4 files in random subdirectories. They have random prefixes which I need to remove. An example of this folder structure is:

```
/
../AFolder/Afolder2/123-01-filename.mp4
../BFolder/Bfolder2/512-01-filname.mp4
../CFolder/Cfolder2/881-01-filename.mp4
```

Basically I want to remove the 3 digit number before every file name along with the dash, so the end files become:

```
/
../AFolder/Afolder2/01-filename.mp4
../BFolder/Bfolder2/01-filname.mp4
../CFolder/Cfolder2/01-filename.mp4
```

I tried to do this by:

```
for file in ./*/*/*mp4
do
    changeto="(echo $name | cut -c4-)"
    echo $name $changeto
    #mv #name $changeto
done
```

but that chops off the first 4 of every directory + file, not just the end file.

Answer (score 1):

Going with your own suggestion of using a shell loop:

```sh
for name in ./*/*/???-*.mp4; do
    filename=${name##*/}         # remove directory path
    filename=${filename#???-}    # remove initial three characters and dash

    # prepend directory path to target filename and rename
    mv "$name" "${name%/*}/$filename"
done
```

This loops over the names that we want to change. For each pathname, the filename portion of the pathname is extracted into the variable `filename` using a standard variable substitution.  From that value, the initial three characters and the dash is removed. The original file can then be renamed using this new `$filename` value.

If you need to be stricter with matching the filenames, ensuring that the first three characters are digits, replace each `?` in the patterns above with `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

---

Using the Perl `rename` utility:

```
rename -v 's/...-([^\/]*\.mp4)$/$1/' ./*/*/???-*.mp4
```

This would apply a Perl substitution to each given filename.  The substitution matches the filename but captures only the bit of the name that we want to keep at the end (a string at the very end containing no `/` character, preceded by the three characters and a dash that we'd like to remove). The matched portion of the pathname is replaced by the captured string.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [mmv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html), for this kind of thing. It allows you to use the wildcards ? and * while moving files. It treats every wildcard as a regex capture group, that's how I think about it, but it uses # instead of \ to access the groups in the replace syntax.

Here's a demo for this problem:

```
$ ls *Folder/*folder2/*
AFolder/Afolder2/123-01-filename.mp4  CFolder/Cfolder2/881-01-filename.mp4 BFolder/Bfolder2/512-01-filname.mp4
$ mmv "*Folder/*folder2/???-*" "#1Folder/#2folder2/#6"
$ ls *Folder/*folder2/*
AFolder/Afolder2/01-filename.mp4  CFolder/Cfolder2/01-filename.mp4 BFolder/Bfolder2/01-filname.mp4
```

The tricky bits are that the first string must basically always be in quotes to avoid invoking the wildcards from the shell itself. Second, remember each ? is its own group, which is how we get up to #6 for the remainder of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find and invoke a shell using `-exec`

```bsh
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    d=${f##*/} d=${d#*[0-9][0-9][0-9]-}
    echo mv -v "$f" "${f%'/'*}/$d"
  done
' _ {} +
```

- The echo is there to tell you how/what is going to be executed, remove it if you think the ouptu is ok

The actual output is like this.

Output

```
renamed './AFolder/Afolder2/123-01-filename.mp4' -> './AFolder/Afolder2/01-filename.mp4'
renamed './BFolder/Bfolder2/512-01-filename.mp4' -> './BFolder/Bfolder2/01-filename.mp4'
renamed './CFolder/Cfolder2/881-01-filename.mp4' -> './CFolder/Cfolder2/01-filename.mp4'
```